# Generate offsets for each row in a dataframe before and after datetime value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ID  time
0   12  2017-09-17 15:30:00
1   13  2017-09-24 18:00:00
```

I would like to add **1h before** each time value and **2 hours after** with a minute frequency:

```
    ID  time
0   12  2017-09-17 14:30:00
1   12  2017-09-17 14:31:00
2   12  2017-09-17 14:32:00
3   12  2017-09-17 14:33:00
...
59  12  2017-09-17 15:29:00
60  12  2017-09-17 15:30:00
...
179 12  2017-09-17 17:29:00
180 12  2017-09-17 17:30:00
181 13  2017-09-24 17:00:00
...
```

Does anyone know how to generate these kinds of offsets?

Comment: Have you looked at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = pd.DataFrame({
               "ID": ["ID1", "ID2"], 
               "time": ["2017-09-17 15:30:00", "2017-09-24 18:00:00"]
               })

data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
print(data.head())
    ID                time
0  ID1 2017-09-17 15:30:00
1  ID2 2017-09-24 18:00:00
```

```py
# Logic
ID = []
time = []
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    tm = row['time']
    split = pd.date_range(
                tm - pd.DateOffset(hours=1), 
                tm + pd.DateOffset(hours=2), 
                freq="1min"
                )

    val = [row['ID']] * len(split)
    ID.extend(val)
    time.extend(split)
```

```py
# Result
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ID, "time": time})
print(df.head(20))
     ID                time
0   ID1 2017-09-17 14:30:00
1   ID1 2017-09-17 14:31:00
2   ID1 2017-09-17 14:32:00
3   ID1 2017-09-17 14:33:00
4   ID1 2017-09-17 14:34:00
5   ID1 2017-09-17 14:35:00
.
.
.
```

Comment: This is perfect skillsmuggler. You got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set `time` to index and `reindex`:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

new_index = pd.concat(pd.date_range(end=a,freq='T', periods=61)
                        .to_series() for a in df.index)

new_df = df.reindex(new_index).bfill().reset_index()
```

Output (`new_df.head()`):

```
                  index       ID
0   2017-09-17 14:30:00     12.0
1   2017-09-17 14:31:00     12.0
2   2017-09-17 14:32:00     12.0
3   2017-09-17 14:33:00     12.0
4   2017-09-17 14:34:00     12.0
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for because the dates don't follow any rules